# WSO2 Governance Registry API for retrieving artifact lists

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-governance-registry

I am using WSO2 Governance Registry (4.6.0) for storing web application catalogues (Countries, Regions, Cities, etc).

I have created Artifact types for each of the catalogues and populated the registry with values. When doing this, WSO2 Governance Registry publishes CRUD methods as showing [here](https://docs.wso2.org/display/Governance460/CRUD+operation+support+for+Configurable+Governance+Artifacts).

I need a way to retrieve the entire list for a artifact type calling Registry API via one single web service and unfortunately couldn't find documentation for it.

Does anyone knows how to obtain this kind of endpoints without custom development? Does Governance Registry has built in this WS?

Answer (score 2):

You can access the configurable governance artifact api in governance api by following [1]. There is a function named getAllGenericArtifacts() to retrieve all artifacts [2]. You can find a sample code from here[3].

[1] - https://docs.wso2.org/display/Governance460/Configurable+Governance+Artifacts+with+API

[2] - https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/trunk/components/governance/org.wso2.carbon.governance.api/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/governance/api/generic/GenericArtifactManager.java

[3] - https://github.com/thushara35/GovernancePopulator/blob/master/src/main/java/org/wso2/sample/rxt/WSDLPopulator.java#L48